# Create an automated confetti explosion HTML for my wix site

Tags: html, velo

I am in the middle of creating an e-commerce store and would love to add a little something special to my check out page.

I was thinking about an explosion of confetti, or glitter or something similar would be nice.  However, I would like it to look elegant and tasteful. I dont mind something like this.....

import Confetti from 'react-dom-confetti';

const config = {
  angle: 51,
  spread: 360,
  startVelocity: 68,
  elementCount: 200,
  decay: 0.87
};
return

**I just have no idea how to put it into HTML format for my WIX site.**

I found this at     https://daniel-lundin.github.io/react-dom-confetti/     -but I know it is missing something major to make it work.... and I dont like that you have to press a button to make it work, I would prefer it to be automatic.

Please help me haha

Kirsten :)

Answer (score 0):

This was an interesting challenge to figure out. So I did!.

What you need to do is embed the javascript that actually performs the confetti effect in an HTMLComponent using Wix Code. It is a little complicated to explain here.

However, I have created an example page that shows the effect working, using Danial Lundin's code, on my examples web site here:

https://stcroppe.wixsite.com/steveonsoftware/example-code/wix-confetti-page

It also shows you the code it uses on the Wix Page to send and receive messages to
the HTML Component that runs the code AND it also shows you the HTML Code I used in the HTML Component to communicate with the Wix page as well as execute the confetti functionality.

Regards
Steve